# How to form dynamic expressions without breaking on types

Tags: python-polars

Any way to make the dynamic polars expressions not break with errors?

Currently I'm just excluding the columns by type, but just wondering if there is a better way.

For example, i have a df coming from parquet, if i just execute an expression on all columns it might break for certain types. Instead I want to contain these errors and possibly return a default value like None or -1 or something else.

```
import polars as pl

df = pl.scan_parquet("/path/to/data/*.parquet")

print(df.schema)
# Prints: {'date_time': <class 'polars.datatypes.Datetime'>, 'incident': <class 'polars.datatypes.Utf8'>, 'address': <class 'polars.datatypes.Utf8'>, 'city': <class 'polars.datatypes.Utf8'>, 'zipcode': <class 'polars.datatypes.Int32'>}
```

Now if i form generic expression on top of this, there are chances it may fail. For example,

```
# Finding positive count across all columns
# Fails due to: exceptions.ComputeError: cannot compare Utf8 with numeric data
print(df.select((pl.all() > 0).count().prefix("__positive_count_")).collect())


# Finding positive count across all columns
# Fails due to: pyo3_runtime.PanicException: 'unique_counts' not implemented for datetime[ns] data types
print(df.select(pl.all().unique_counts().prefix("__unique_count_")).collect())


# Finding positive count across all columns
# Fails due to: exceptions.SchemaError: Series dtype Int32 != utf8
# Note: this could have been avoided by doing an explict cast to string first
print(df.select((pl.all().str.lengths() > 0).count().prefix("__empty_count_")).collect())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll keep to things that work in lazy mode, as it appears that you are working in lazy mode with Parquet files.

Let's use this data as an example:

```py
import polars as pl
from datetime import datetime

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "col_int": [-2, -2, 0, 2, 2],
        "col_float": [-20.0, -10, 10, 20, 20],
        "col_date": pl.date_range(datetime(2020, 1, 1), datetime(2020, 5, 1), "1mo"),
        "col_str": ["str1", "str2", "", None, "str5"],
        "col_bool": [True, False, False, True, False],
    }
).lazy()
df.collect()
```

```
shape: (5, 5)
┌─────────┬───────────┬─────────────────────┬─────────┬──────────┐
│ col_int ┆ col_float ┆ col_date            ┆ col_str ┆ col_bool │
│ ---     ┆ ---       ┆ ---                 ┆ ---     ┆ ---      │
│ i64     ┆ f64       ┆ datetime[ns]        ┆ str     ┆ bool     │
╞═════════╪═══════════╪═════════════════════╪═════════╪══════════╡
│ -2      ┆ -20.0     ┆ 2020-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ str1    ┆ true     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ -2      ┆ -10.0     ┆ 2020-02-01 00:00:00 ┆ str2    ┆ false    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 0       ┆ 10.0      ┆ 2020-03-01 00:00:00 ┆         ┆ false    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2       ┆ 20.0      ┆ 2020-04-01 00:00:00 ┆ null    ┆ true     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2       ┆ 20.0      ┆ 2020-05-01 00:00:00 ┆ str5    ┆ false    │
└─────────┴───────────┴─────────────────────┴─────────┴──────────┘
```

##### Using the `col` Expression

One feature of the `col` expression is that you can supply a datatype, or even a list of datatypes.  For example, if we want to contain our queries to floats, we can do the following:

```py
df.select((pl.col(pl.Float64) > 0).sum().suffix("__positive_count_")).collect()
```

```
shape: (1, 1)
┌────────────────────────────┐
│ col_float__positive_count_ │
│ ---                        │
│ u32                        │
╞════════════════════════════╡
│ 3                          │
└────────────────────────────┘
```

(Note: `(pl.col(...) > 0)` creates a series of boolean values that need to be summed, not counted)

To include more than one datatype, you can supply a list of datatypes to `col`.

```py
df.select(
    (pl.col([pl.Int64, pl.Float64]) > 0).sum().suffix("__positive_count_")
).collect()
```

```
shape: (1, 2)
┌──────────────────────────┬────────────────────────────┐
│ col_int__positive_count_ ┆ col_float__positive_count_ │
│ ---                      ┆ ---                        │
│ u32                      ┆ u32                        │
╞══════════════════════════╪════════════════════════════╡
│ 2                        ┆ 3                          │
└──────────────────────────┴────────────────────────────┘
```

You can also combine these into the same select statement if you'd like.

```py
df.select(
    [
        (pl.col(pl.Utf8).str.lengths() == 0).sum().suffix("__empty_count"),
        pl.col(pl.Utf8).is_null().sum().suffix("__null_count"),
        (pl.col([pl.Float64, pl.Int64]) > 0).sum().suffix("_positive_count"),
    ]
).collect()
```

```
shape: (1, 4)
┌──────────────────────┬─────────────────────┬──────────────────────────┬────────────────────────┐
│ col_str__empty_count ┆ col_str__null_count ┆ col_float_positive_count ┆ col_int_positive_count │
│ ---                  ┆ ---                 ┆ ---                      ┆ ---                    │
│ u32                  ┆ u32                 ┆ u32                      ┆ u32                    │
╞══════════════════════╪═════════════════════╪══════════════════════════╪════════════════════════╡
│ 1                    ┆ 1                   ┆ 3                        ┆ 2                      │
└──────────────────────┴─────────────────────┴──────────────────────────┴────────────────────────┘
```

The Cookbook has a handy list of [datatypes](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/datatypes.html).

##### Using the `exclude` expression

Another handy trick is to use the `exclude` expression.  With this, we can select all columns **except** columns of certain datatypes.  For example:

```py
df.select(
    [
        pl.exclude(pl.Utf8).max().suffix("_max"),
        pl.exclude([pl.Utf8, pl.Boolean]).min().suffix("_min"),
    ]
).collect()
```

```
shape: (1, 7)
┌─────────────┬───────────────┬─────────────────────┬──────────────┬─────────────┬───────────────┬─────────────────────┐
│ col_int_max ┆ col_float_max ┆ col_date_max        ┆ col_bool_max ┆ col_int_min ┆ col_float_min ┆ col_date_min        │
│ ---         ┆ ---           ┆ ---                 ┆ ---          ┆ ---         ┆ ---           ┆ ---                 │
│ i64         ┆ f64           ┆ datetime[ns]        ┆ u32          ┆ i64         ┆ f64           ┆ datetime[ns]        │
╞═════════════╪═══════════════╪═════════════════════╪══════════════╪═════════════╪═══════════════╪═════════════════════╡
│ 2           ┆ 20.0          ┆ 2020-05-01 00:00:00 ┆ 1            ┆ -2          ┆ -20.0         ┆ 2020-01-01 00:00:00 │
└─────────────┴───────────────┴─────────────────────┴──────────────┴─────────────┴───────────────┴─────────────────────┘
```

##### Unique counts

One caution: `unique_counts` results in Series of varying lengths.

```py
df.select(pl.col("col_int").unique_counts().prefix(
    "__unique_count_")).collect()
```

```
shape: (3, 1)
┌────────────────────────┐
│ __unique_count_col_int │
│ ---                    │
│ u32                    │
╞════════════════════════╡
│ 2                      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1                      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2                      │
└────────────────────────┘
```

```py
df.select(pl.col("col_float").unique_counts().prefix(
    "__unique_count_")).collect()
```

```
shape: (4, 1)
┌──────────────────────────┐
│ __unique_count_col_float │
│ ---                      │
│ u32                      │
╞══════════════════════════╡
│ 1                        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1                        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1                        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2                        │
└──────────────────────────┘
```

As such, these should not be combined into the same results.  Each column/Series of a DataFrame must have the same length.

Comment: great answer @cbilot - will we ever be able to unique_count on datetime types?

Comment: @Jenobi - Hmmm, 'not implemented' excpetions.  I've logged a feature request.  You can track it here: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/3689